# Is there a way to make every property in a json required?

Tags: json, swagger

I have a json file from a swagger definition and want to manipulate it so that every definition in this file has required properties

Here one example:
[image: Example]

and within this json there are multiple nodes like this and after the additionalproperties I want to also add a required with all the properties available.

Is there a tool that somehow can do this automatically as I have like 50+ nodes I do not want to make this manually if possible

Looked at json editor online if it works somehow, but did not find a solution